# How to determine the behavior of complicated source code quickly?

Tags: c++, python

I am interested in zcash (https://github.com/zcash/zcash) and the theory behind it. Therefore, I download the source codes of zcash to trace it.  The codes comprise C++,python and shell scripts. How to determine the behavior of these codes quickly? I tried UML revere engineering, but doesn't really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in the theory, then read the papers written for it.  If you're interested in how the code runs, then hopefully someone wrote documentation for that.  If you want a quick, automatic way of learning this, you are out of luck because static analysis cannot, in general, describe the behavior of a computer program (the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).  Finally, if you want a quick way to determine the behavior for yourself, I can only give general advice like "work backwards from the main function" and "figure out what each function or class does".  Program design is an art.

Comment: Is there any possibility of multiple main fuctions(may be one from C++ ,one from python)? I examine the main function in bitcoind.cpp. That's too simple. It only starts connection. How about other functions( proof of work,ledger)?

Comment: @aswe2277 "It only starts connection" no, by definition the whole program depends on what happens in `main`. Try applying the "figure out what each function or class does" to **everything** in `main`

Comment: So when the binaries start, it executes all functions in main.cpp in order? Not main function in bitcoind.cpp?

Comment: I search for main.cpp and can only find it in bitcoind.cpp.

Comment: @aswe2277: FWIW, "It only starts connection" - seems to me it does far more than that. The last line in main calls `AppInit`, which calls a lot of other functions. I recommend to use a debugger, set a break point at a suitable line in the code and step through it.

Comment: Thank all your help. Last Question: Why don't the programmers put main function in main.cpp? I am really curious about it.

Comment: We don't know, here is the very wrong place to ask for. Better ask at the zcash forum.